# How do I access the data returned from my firestore database query?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux-firebase

I'm working on creating a function that queries my firestore database based on the name entered into an input box and returns some data. Now, my query works and logs to the console. The problem is that I'm having quite a bit of trouble accessing this data so I can render it onto the DOM. How is the best way to access this data?

I've gotten my entire database to render onto the DOM by using this code =>

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log(state.firestore.queries)
    return {
        dogs: state.firestore.ordered.dogs,
        auth: state.firebase.auth
    }
}


export default compose(
    connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
    firestoreConnect(() => {
        return [
            {
                collection: 'dogs',
            }

        ]
    })
)(ManageDogs)
```

But when I structure my firestoreConnect() function as follows=>

```
export default compose(
    connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
    firestoreConnect(() => {
        return [
            {
                collection: 'dogs',
                where: ['name', '==', 'Fido']
            }

        ]
    })
)(ManageDogs)
```

The query logs to the console as follows =>

```
{status: {…}, data: {…}, ordered: {…}, listeners: {…}, errors: {…}, …}
composite: {dogs: {…}}
data: {dogs: {…}}
errors: {byQuery: {…}, allIds: Array(0)}
listeners: {byId: {…}, allIds: Array(2)}
ordered: {dogs: Array(4)}
queries:
    dogs?where=name:==:Fido: {data: {…}, collection: "dogs", where: Array(3)}
__proto__: Object
status: {requesting: {…}, requested: {…}, timestamps: {…}}
__proto__: Object
```

The queried data ends up in the value state.firestore.queries.dogs?where=name:==:Fido, but when I try to use this path in mapStateToProps, it returns a value of undefined.

How is the best way to access this data? Has anyone ever dealt with this before? Is there a better way to query the firestore database?